# typecast list to string using hibernate in java

Tags: java, hibernate

i tried to typecast a list data to string but its showing error as java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
please help me to solve this issue.this is done using hibernate.

```
for(int i2=1; i2<=gantttablecolnameList.size(); ++i2)
{
   columnname= (String) ((List)gantttablecolnameList.get(i1)).get(0);
}
```

this list contains tables column name.

Comment: *java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List* That is `true` . What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: You shouldn't start with Hibernate until you have a sound understanding of Java data types. How is `gantttablecolnameList` declared? And are you sure your loop starts at 1? (List indexes count from 0)

Comment: gantttablecolnameList  is declared as  List gantttablecolnameList=new ArrayList();

Answer (score 1):

If your `List gantttablecolnameList` really have `String` then try this :

```
for(int i2=0; i2<gantttablecolnameList.size(); i2++)
{
  columnname= (String) (gantttablecolnameList.get(i2));
}
```

You are doing this :

```
(List)gantttablecolnameList.get(i1)
```

Assuming your  `List gantttablecolnameList` contains `String` ,`gantttablecolnameList.get(i1)` will give you an `Object` which is actually a `String` instance for the index specified by the runtime value of `i1` . So , in a nutshell you are trying this :

```
 (List)"someString";
```

which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 columnname= (String) ((List)gantttablecolnameList).get(0));
```

in `(List)gantttablecolnameList.get(i1))` the `gantttablecolnameList.get(i1)` will give you the element ..not the list.

But really you have to check null conditions.Yours is as of now `NUll PATTERN`

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. Downcast to `List <String>` instead of the raw type you have now;
2. Iterate over the list using the enhanced for loop. Don't do index-based iteration;
3. Once you have dealt with the above, your code will be simple enough to make the bug simply evaporate:

   ```
    for (String columname : (List<String>) ganttablecolumnlist) ...
   ```